# How to check if isolcpus is configured & working?

Tags: linux, performance, linux-kernel, cpu, low-latency

I am using RHEL and i have configured isolcups= in /boot/grub/grub.conf file so that I can isolate some cpu from os scheduling processes. Now I want to check if those cpu's are isolated or they are still using OS scheduling algorithm.

The machine config is twin 5690 processor in hyper threaded mode. 
So a total of 24 cores. 
I want to isolate 6 cores for an application.

However when i do "top", I find that there are some system processes running on those cores. I am pasting the supposed to be isolated 12th core.

100 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.01 migration/11                                                                                     11
  101 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/11                                                                                     11
  102 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/11:0                                                                                     11
  103 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/11:0H                                                                                    11
What is sure shot way of checking isolated cpu in linux?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve it , It using only those cpu that are not isolated.

I did stress test on it, and it is only taking non-isolated cpu.The only chang i made is config file "/boot/grub/grub.cfg" and reboot the system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use stress test and check if it is using isolated core or not.